# NLog. Change class name

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

i'm wondering if there is any way to change class name of logger instance at runtime ? i want not to create logger in every class but to inject it via constructor. but after i do it i get in file wrong class name which invokes the event. Project structure is like this

```
public class c1
{
    private Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    public void doSmth()
    {
        c2 myC2= new c2(_logger);
        myC2.LogSomething();
    }

    public void LogSomething()
    {
        _logger.Info("c1 test");
    }
}


public class c2
{
    private Logger _logger;

    public c2(Logger logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public void LogSomething() {
        _logger.Info("c2 test");
    }
}
```

everything woks fine but in log file we get

> 2011-09-07 09:33:59.7521|INFO|c1|c1 test 
>   2011-09-07 09:33:59.7611|INFO|c1|c2 test

Comment: Is there a specific reason why You don't want to create logger for each class?

Comment: This is the normal behavior. Your logger is only initialized in `c1` class, so the logger name will always be `c1`. If you want the logger name to be your current class name, the best way is still to create a logger in every class with `private Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`. I don't see why you don't want to do it. Can you explain why is it a problem for you?

Comment: The logger instance can be static. This way, you save CPU time and resources. private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the `${logger}` layout renderer, use the [`${callsite}`](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Callsite_layout_renderer) renderer.

```
<target xsi:type="Trace" 
            name="t"  
 layout="${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false}
 | ${message}" />
```

This should produce your expected result.